# scroll change section javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to create a page that when user scroll to bottom with the mouse or scroll bar in browser, a section be change, it also with 400 or a an arbitrary number.

also when user scroll to top this changes undo.

when scroll bottom

```html
<h1>hello<h1> <!-- show 400px scroll bottom -->
<h1>my dear<h1><!-- show next 400px scroll bottom  mean 800px -->
<h1>friend<h1><!-- show next 400px scroll bottom mean 1200px -->
```

when scroll to top

```html
<h1>friend<h1><!-- show next 400px scroll top mean 1200px -->
<h1>my dear<h1><!-- show  next 400px scroll top mean 800px -->
<h1>hello<h1> <!-- show  400px scroll top mean 400px -->
```

my html code is

```html
<div class="box">
<h1>hello<h1>
<h1>my dear<h1>
<h1>friend<h1>
</div>
```

i want to do this just with javascript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop; // this is must to minus from a OfsetTop section before this
    var element = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
 console.log(Math.round(winScroll)); 
    for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
        var min = 500 * i;
        var max = (1000 * i)-(500 * (i-1));
//         console.log(Math.round(winScroll));
    if(winScroll >= min && winScroll < max){
        element[i].className = "show";
         console.log(Math.round(winScroll)); 
    }else{
         element[i].className = 'hide';

    } 


    }


}
```